# mat-button-toggle-checked with dynamic style + Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, dynamic, styles

I'm trying to customize my button-toggle when it is checked but my current code is not working...

Here is the actual code

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #mytoggle (change)="selectoption($event)" value="{{num}}">
            <mat-button-toggle [style.background-color]="getColor(op)" *ngFor="let op of mylist" [value]="op">{{op}}</mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Here is my method on .ts

```
 getColorChecked(opcao: any){
        if ( opcao === 2){
            return '#EA0B28 !important;';
        }else{
            return '#9d9b9a !important;';
        }
    }
```

Here is my scss file

```
.mat-button-toggle-group, .mat-button-toggle-standalone{
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.02), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.01), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}   
 .mat-button-toggle{
      border-right: 1px solid #cccccc40 !important;
      font-weight: 400;
      width: 50px !important;
      padding: 0px !important;
      background: #f7f9fbc7 !important;
      div{
        padding: 0px !important;
      }
    }
    .mat-button-toggle-checked {
      color: #fbfbfb;
    }
```

It's not working... There's a best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: Same color for all selected buttons

You can add these `CSS Class`:

```
.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard {
    background-color: #9d9b9a;
    color:white;
}

.mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: #EA0B28;
    color:white;
}
```

[image]

---

**Solution 2**: Single color by selected buttons

You can add these `CSS Class`: `:nth-child(x)` Target items based on their position in the document

```
.bg-red:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}

.bg-green:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
    color:white;
}

.bg-blue:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue!important;
    color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group>
  <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let op of mylist" 
    [value]="op" 
    [ngClass]="{'bg-red':selected === 1,'bg-green':selected === 2,'bg-blue':selected === 3}" 
    (click)="selected = op"> {{op}}
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

TS:

```
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  mylist = [1,2,3];
  selected;
}
```

[image]

---

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-mat-button-toggle-checked-with-dynamic-style)

Comment: Thanks for answer ! I'd try on css class but I need diferent color in every button. For example, the button where is write "Bold" need to be red, the other green, only when they are checked...

Comment: This doesnt work anymore.... It is overwritten by the default style without important